# Как правильно написать запрос. MySQL - SUM - GROUP BY

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Смысл БД в хранении информации, по проведённым с курсантами занятиям. Инструктор провёл занятие с курсантом и БД вносится: ... дата, время начала, время окончания, общее время ...
Инструктор может провести занятие сразу с двумя курсантами, но в БД вносится запись для каждого курсанта. Получается, что 2022-08-18 мы имеем две записи с одинаковым временем начала и конца.
В сводной таблице надо вывести итоги и просуммировать total_time для одного инструктора, чтобы понять, сколько он начитал часов, например за месяц, и так как он проводил занятие 1 час, то эти две записи нужно сгруппировать, чтобы получить правильное время работы инструктора за выбранный период. Результатом запроса должно быть лишь одно число, можно в секундах, я уже разберусь. Записей в БД порядка 20 тыс.

SELECT `date`,`time_start_taxi`, SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( `total_time` ) )  AS sum_total_time  FROM `tor_mission_complete` GROUP BY `date` AND `time_start_taxi`

Ответ БД:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *Инструктор может провести занятие сразу с двумя курсантами, но в БД вносится запись для каждого курсанта.* Срочно идите читать теорию о нормальных формах. А потом переделайте этот ужастик во вменяемую структуру, на которой требуемые данные будут получаться легко и просто. *дата, время начала, время окончания, общее время* - переопределённые данные. Достаточно хранить штамп времени начала и длительность, остальное считается.

Comment: Возможно я не понял всю глубину вашего совета. Вы предлагаете убрать время окончания, потому что это лишняя информация, согласен. Хорошо, убрал. Но проблема-то осталась.

Comment: Переопределённые данные - это мелкая проблема. Основная проблема - это денормализация, которую и надо ликвидировать.

Comment: Так как мне запрос-то написать? :)

Comment: Иначе придётся в подзапросе получать уники занятий (DISTINCT), а во внешнем запросе уже группировать.

Comment: Я создал две таблицы. 1 - основная, хранит инфу по занятию указанную выше, 2 - это упражнения, которые были проведены за 1 час занятия. Как мне ещё разбить основную таблицу, чтобы было проще делать запросы. Это здесь два курсанта, а программа позволяет проводить занятие с 10ю курсантами и более. Будет на каждого курсанта запись.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На нынешней структуре это будет

```sql
SELECT инструктор, дата, SUM(длительность)
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT инструктор, дата, начало, длительность
       FROM таблица ) AS алиас
GROUP BY 1, 2
```